# Why are Relay Modern QueryRenderer render props undefined?

Tags: javascript, graphql, relaymodern

This is my first attempt at using Relay Modern.
Fetching for a specific User from a `PostgraphQL GraphQL Server`.
It is fetching the data successfully but not passing to render function:

```
import {createFragmentContainer, QueryRenderer, graphql} from 'react-relay'
import environment from 'environment'

@CSSModules(styles) export default class Profile extends Component {   
  render() {
    var {props: {children}} = this
    return (
      <QueryRenderer
        environment={environment}
        query={graphql`
          query ProfileQuery {
            userById(id: "f0301eaf-55ad-46db-ac90-b52d6138489e") {
              firstName
              userName
            }
          }
        `}
        render={({error, relayProps}) => {
          if (error) {
            return <div>{error.message}</div>
          } else if (relayProps) {
            ...
          }
          return <div>Loading...</div>
        }}
      />
    )   
  }
}
```

Only "Loading..." is rendered.

I am guessing because it successfully fetches data that the graphql server and environment are ok.

I am not using React 16 and the project also uses Redux.

**Any suggestions please as to why relayProps wouldn't have a value (e.g. relayProps.user)?**

One further thing that may help, the environment (file) is in the main application and the `QueryRenderer` and components are in an imported npm package (to be shared across a number of applications).  As mentioned, the query seems to work fine so I did not think this was a problem. I also run the relay compiler on the package but not the main application since there are no relay components there.

Just in case it's needed the environment is setup using:

```
const {
  Environment,
  Network,
  RecordSource,
  Store,
} = require('relay-runtime')

// Instantiate Store for Cached Data
const store = new Store(new RecordSource())

// Create Network for GraphQL Server
const network = Network.create((operation, variables) => {
  // GraphQL Endpoint
  return fetch(config.gqlapiProtocol + "://" + config.gqlapiHost + config.gqlapiUri + "/a3/graphql" , {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': "application/json",
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: operation.text,
      variables,
    }),
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
})

// Instantiate Environment
const environment = new Environment({
  network,
  store,
})

// Export environment
export default environment
```

Comment: Are you sure your network layer is being called?. Do you see your data and/or errors in the response.json(). In my case I have a subsequent `.then(json => {
        // Allow Relay onError to get fired in case of errors in response
        // See: https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1816
        // NOTICE: that data might contain values even when errors present
        if(json.errors && json.errors.length > 0) {
          return Promise.reject(json);
        }
        return Promise.resolve(json);
      })`

Comment: Yes, I see the correct data in the response.  This is why I felt confident network was ok.  No error in call to render either.  Thank you for your comments.  I will try your suggestion though, nice addition.

Answer (score 1):

`props` are not `relayprops`

```
    render={({ error, props }) => {
      if (error) {
        return <div>{error.message}</div>;
      } else if (props) {
        ...
      }
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }}
```

and

```
fetch(GRAPHQL_URL, {
  method: 'POST',
  get headers() {
    return {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query: operation.text, // GraphQL text from input
    variables
  })
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    // https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1816
    if (operation.query.operation === 'mutation' && json.errors) {
      return Promise.reject(json);
    }

    return Promise.resolve(json);
  })
);
```

Comment: Thank you but I am not sure the name of the parameter (props, relayProps, x, y, z, ...) makes any difference in this case?

I think the code is just defining a function that takes a deconstructed object with two attributes and uses those attributes within the function.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `render={({ error, props, retry }) => {  }}` or `render={(relayProps) => { const { error, props, retry } = relayProps; }}`

do you understand it?

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. The name matters if you are trying to destructure the parameter, he's right.

Comment: it makes no difference, it's just ES6 Destructuring assignment syntax